# Storing data own adapter after rotating

Tags: android, listview, rotation

I have application with listview(one line contains textview, imageview, ratingbar) and my own adapter. When I rotate the screen after sorting listview (I choose this option in menu), it backs to form before sorting. 
I tried override onSaveInstanceState:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("listView", listView.onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

and fragment onCreate:

```
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     if(savedInstanceState!=null)
     {
        mListInstanceState=savedInstanceState.getParcelable("listView");
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(mListInstanceState);
     }
```

But it doesn't work. Should I override onRestoreInstanceState too or use something else?

Comment: Do you save your adapter?  When you rotate the screen, everything gets restarted and your code will go through its initialization again.

Comment: I understand it, I'd like to do it and then read at beginning on oncreate f.e.. But I don't know what should I use, sharedpreferences (it seems to be strenuous) or something else? I'm a beginner:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when orientation change your `Activity` is recreated and when `onCreate()` is called you are setting the adapter with the default list items.

If you don’t maintain different `layout` for landscape/portrait, you can simply avoid the `Activity` recreate by just adding `configChanges` in manifest for your `Activity`

```
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  // add this line
```

This will avoid recreating the `Activity` and same layout will be used to fit on screen width. Make sure your listView layout width is set to `match_parent`.

If you still want your `Activity` to recreate, then you need to remember the last selected filter when `onSaveInstanceState` is called on orientation change

```
  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)= {
     outState.putString(“selectedFilter","some name");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And then when `onCreate` in called after rotate, you can get the selectedFilter name

```
  String filterName = null;

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        filterName = savedInstanceState.getString("lastFilter");
    }
```

Finally , set the `listView` with items based on the filter name.

```
 if(filterName != null && filterName.equalsIgnoreCase("some name")){
        // filtered list items
 } else {
         // default list items
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works:) I had to change initialization of filterName, cause it spoiled at rotate screen again.